# Modify files when git commit or merge to a branch

Tags: git

Is it possible to modify the files when `git commit` or `git merge` is triggered before they will **actually** be added to `develop` branch history? How?

Let say I want to put a `/*js*/` at the end of all the .js files that are modified before the commit or merge.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Seems to kind of go against the philosophy of version control, to have it "silently" add new content to the files when completing an operation.

Comment: You can add all the files that you want to your local workspace before a push to remote o final repository. include your js file into your local git workspace and do git add -A git -m commit and then when you are ready to push, do git push origin master.

Comment: Are you asking whether a pre-commit hook can alter the contents of the index such that those new contents are what is used in the commit?

Comment: i want my team to be free whatever coding style they prefer but when they put something to develop, it should follow the agreed coding style of the team. What do you suggest guys. I originally thought of writing a maven or gulp plugin for this, but it's not smooth

Comment: So what you need, really, is a linter of some sort rather than a `git` pre-commit hook (in order to enforce the common coding style).

Comment: As far as I know linter only suggest but not modify the file. I dont want developers spending time to correct the styling, I want this to be automated --- if it is possible or there's a cleaner way. If only I can load a script to the git hooks

Comment: I don't think you are giving your coders enough credit in their ability to conform to a mutually agreed-upon coding style.